# Do I have to commit my changes before pulling in Git?

Tags: git

It looks like I'm missing basic understanding of `git pull` and `git commit`, let's say I'm working on branch and it was updated by other developer while I was doing my job locally. Should I commit changes before issuing `git pull` or should I do `git pull` and then do `git commit`?

Comment: First pull, then reapply your changes, then commit.

Comment: Rebasing is not always necessary (remember that not everyone uses the same git workflow). If you commit before pulling, git should be able to merge your changes just fine.

Comment: This question is very likely a duplicate.

Comment: You should learn how to use `git stash`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do a commit anytime you want - all your commits are local.

It's only when you need to `push` to the server that you need to have its latest copy. So it's a good idea that you always `pull` from the remote repository before you `push` your changes.

So, I think what you mean is "Should I *push* changes before issuing git pull or should I do git pull and then do git *push*". You should ideally `pull` before you `push` which adheres to the basic idea of adding code to the most recent copy of the public repository.

You might be notified of some merge conflicts obtained by merging the public repository, which you need to resolve before you can finally push your changes.

Comment: Actually, it's best to avoid merging into a dirty working copy, so you should either commit before pulling, or stash your changes before doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Since git doesn't let you merge when you have uncommitted changes you need to address those changes before doing a git pull (which does a fetch then merge).

You can either

1. checkout to erase those changes
2. make a commit to save them
3. my preferred halfway approach - [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

By doing a `git stash` first, you can then pull (fetch and merge) in the changes, then `git stash pop` to apply your changes back in.  If there are conflicts, the stash isn't dropped, and you get a chance to resolve those conflicts.

Comment: This is not entirely correct, there are cases when Git will actually let you merge even when you have uncommitted changes. Still, as you've pointed out, it's best to commit or stash your changes before merging.

Answer (score 4):

If you have uncommitted changes to existing files in your branch git won't let you pull. You can either commit what you have, or use the `--autostash` flag when pulling and then you'll be able to pull.

Comment: This is partially correct, Git will allow the pull in some cases, but not in others. Still, it's best to commit or stash your changes before pulling anyways, either way.